# LINQ where clause combined with Func<> and Foreach

Tags: c#

What am i trying to do:

I have a list of extensions (.mpg, .avi, .jpg) ... and a list of filenames (stuff.jpg, dogs.txt, movie.avi).

I want to compare the list of filenames with the list of extensions, and only keep the files where the extensions match. In the case of the example above that would be stuff.jpg and movie.avi, dogs.txt should be ignored.

How i am doing it:

I have a List of strings (file extensions like .mp3, mp4, .avi...):

```
        List<String>  extensions = new List<string>();
        extensions.Add(".mp4");
        extensions.Add(".mp3");
        extensions.Add(".avi");
        extensions.Add(".mkv");
        extensions.Add(".mpeg");
        extensions.Add(".mpg");
```

I also have an IEnumerable containing several files.

What i want to do is check every file inside the IEnumerable to see if it has an extension matching with one of the extensions in my list above here (so .mpg,.mp3...).

right now im doing this:

```
    var files = dir.EnumerateFiles();
    var newlist = files.Where(doesItMatch).Select(x => x).ToList();

    private Func<FileInfo, bool> doesItMatch = x =>
            {
                return x.Extension == ".mp3";
            };
```

This works, but obviously it will only check if it matches ".mp3". The thing is that i dont want to start doing something like

```
where x == ".mp4" || x == ".avi" || x == ".mpg" ....
```

I basically want to iterate through every element in my list of extensions and match that with the current extension of the file in the IEnumerable.

I've tried doing a foreach like this:

```
 var newlist = files.Where(file => extensions.ForEach(ext => file.Extension == ext) ).Select(x => x).ToList();
```

But this gives me an error on the  `file.Extension == ext` part, stating that only "assignment, call... can be used as a statement".

So my question is, can I use the `Func<>` described above combined with some sort of foreach over the list of extensions ? Or should i look for another way of doing this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
                     .Where(f => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(f).Extension))
                     .ToList();
```

---

and using your `doesItMatch`

```
var extensions = new HashSet<string>(new[] { ".mp4", ".mp3", ".avi",".mkv",".mpeg",".mpg" });

Func<string, bool> doesItMatch = x => extensions.Contains(new FileInfo(x).Extension);

var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
                     .Where(f => doesItMatch(f))
                     .ToList();
```

Comment: I think new FileInfo(f) should be new FileInfo(f.FullName), but apart from that it works!. Thanks alot. Also, is it a bad practice to use a Func<> for this particular case ? Or is it acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

Another way which avoids having to create a func<> to search would be to just use the ANY linq method:

```
List<string> extenstions = new List<string>
{
   ".txt",
   ".pdf"
};

DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop");

IEnumerable<FileInfo> foundFiles = dir.EnumerateFiles().Where(f => ext.Any(e => f.Extension == e));
```